# how to upload multiple images for each image need to upload smal medium large images #angular 6

Tags: angular

how to upload multiple images . for each image need to upload small medium large images.

I have a scenario where i have to create multiple file upload fields dynamically using reactive forms with form array and upload multiple image for that particular field in angular 5 or angular reactive forms and the image needs to be displayed parallel to that form field name .

Please help with me with any sample code in stack blitz or from any links.

Anyway thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please go through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide us with the code you tried with so we can help you with the issue. Since we can't see what have you tried with, we can't actually pinpoint the problem in your code.

Comment: sure @HimanshuBansal